# How to code R so it runs one line at a time

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a fairly simple program to run some calculations (just for fun)
I want to be able to just input 2 variables, and do some basic calculations with them, all in one run of the code, whereas instead I'm having to run 3 different sections in order to get it to work (line 1, line 2, lines 3 and 4)
It's probably just a dumb error somewhere, but how do I get it to work properly?

```
odds1 <- as.integer(readline(prompt="enter first part of odds"))
odds2 <- as.integer(readline(prompt="enter second part of odds"))
newOdds <- (odds2)/(odds2+odds1)
print(newOdds)
```

Expectation: enter 2 variables, and receive the calculated result
Reality:
> odds1 <- as.integer(readline(prompt="enter first part of odds"))
enter first part of oddsodds2 <- as.integer(readline(prompt="enter second part of odds"))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
> newOdds <- (odds2)/(odds2+odds1)
> print(newOdds)
[1] NA

Comment: Technically, you can make all codes one liner by using `;`)

Comment: Why would you want to do *any* of this in such a clumsy way?  Once you learn what a closure -- i.e.  function -- is, you'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by defining a function that wraps up all our code. That way, we only need to call the function and it will give the expected output without filling the console with lines of code.

For example, if we define the following function:

```r
get_odds <- function() {
  odds1 <- as.integer(readline(prompt="\n  Enter first part of odds: "))
  odds2 <- as.integer(readline(prompt="  Enter second part of odds: "))
  newOdds <- (odds2)/(odds2+odds1)
  print(newOdds)
}
```

Then when we call the function, it will look like this:

```r
> get_odds()

  Enter first part of odds: 1
  Enter second part of odds: 2
[1] 0.6666667
```

Comment: or just put the 4 lines between braces `{ }`

Comment: But of course the OP should recognize that feeding all "oddsX" as arguments to a function is the way to go.